# Rabbitmq - Priority queue message processing

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp, spring-amqp

We have an application where we have 150 queues and now we want to introduce priority messages for all these queues.

1. All these queues are durable and persistent in nature.
2. Is it possible to convert these queues into priority queueues ? Do we have any documentation(s) available for this ? Maybe I missed it in the docs.
3. We have a plan that we will introduce 2 levels in priority either 0 or 1(default). https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html I found that
   with more level of priority we need more CPU resources.

I didn't find what will be the scale or how much CPU resources will increase on which factor like no. of messages ? Do we have any stats or study available ?

Comment: Consider to ask such a question directly in RabbitMQ Support: https://www.rabbitmq.com/#community. Does look like there is anything to be done from Spring perspective: only that `maxPriority` on the `Queue` you declare in your application context.

Comment: You cannot modify a queue configuration once it is created; you need to delete and redeclare the queue with the new settings.